# How to constantly sort and refresh elements (e.g. elevator target floor)

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

I was wondering if any of you Guys could help me out with my school project. I'm working on elevator simulator in WPF. It's quite simple how it works, you press a button on certain floor and elevator goes there. I managed to achieve animation effect by using async method for animation and waiting between iterations like `await Task.Delay(10)`.

This is how my code looks:

6 buttons on different floors (from 4 to -1). Every button is calling `animation(x)` method, where x = floor where button is placed. This is button 4 for example:

```
        async private void buttonna4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        animation(4);
    }
```

So from clicking this button we go to `animation(x)` method, which looks like that:

```
public async Task animation(int go_where_from_button)                 
    {
        await semafor.WaitAsync();
        {
            go_where = convert_floor(go_where_from_button);
            try
            {
                if (go_where < Windajo.Margin.Top) //going up
                {
                    for (int i = Convert.ToInt16(Windajo.Margin.Top); i >= go_where; i--)
                    {
                        await gui_elements(i);
                    }
                }

                if (go_where > Windajo.Margin.Top)  //going down
                {
                    for (int i = Convert.ToInt16(Windajo.Margin.Top); i <= go_where; i++)
                    {
                        await gui_elements(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                label.Content = "some exception";
            }
            finally
            {
                semafor.Release();
            }
        }
    }
```

where:

`SemaphoreSlim semafor = new SemaphoreSlim(1);` which I use to prevent elevator from going upwards and downwards at once.

`go_where` is converted value of how far elevator should go till it stops (because I use margins to determine whether elevator moved to desired floor or not).

`await gui_elements(i)` is a method where I've put all my elevator things like elevator itself, doors, screen with current floor etc so it looks like:

```
public async Task gui_elements(int i)
{
Windajo.Margin = new Thickness(Windajo.Margin.Left, i, Windajo.Margin.Right, Windajo.Margin.Bottom);
//OTHER ELEMENTS................
await Task.Delay(10);
}
```

Now it works like that: lets assume that we are on floor 0 I push `buttonna3`, `buttonna4`, `buttonna1`. Elevator will go in exact that order: floor 3 -> floor 4 -> floor 1.

**And here is my question:** how to make it sort floors correctly to work like normal elevator? So in this case to go floor 4 -> floor 3 -> floor 1 (or floor 1 -> floor 3 -> floor 4). And while it's already moving for example from floor 1 to floor 3 to react if someone pushes button on floor 2.

I was struggling with this all day long. First I tried to make `List()` of floors desired and then `Distinct` not unique floors and `Sort` them but it was not working as it should because (I used foreach and it couldnt update the list while doing operations, at least this is what I think).

Could anyone give me a hint of not complicated and correct way of solving this problem?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What exactly is the project?  Do you have to certain elements?  For instance, do you need to use a semaphore, or is that just the first thing you thought of?

Comment: Yes, list of things I should use: semaphore, mutex, lock, possix (it should be project made in C but I decided to surprise my teacher. Is there anything I can use instead of possix because he told me that c# dont have it)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I dont have to use everything on this method. There are a lot more like: opening/closing doors, alarm button, protected floor (by PIN pad).

Comment: "5 buttons on different floors (from 4 to -1)."  So floors 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1?  Might want to count them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't call `animation` method directly from `buttonDown` event.
Instead of this, you can create List of inputs and create a `Timer` and put all the elevator logic in `Timer.Tick` handler.

The main idea and the main issue is how to calculate next floor (targetFloor). 
I suggest to create a list of inputs  `List<int> inputs`, flag that shows is elevator go down or up `bool IsGoingUp` and two int variables - currentFloor and targetFloor and recalculate target floor every time when user clicks a button, based on direction and on inputs.

Something like this.

```
    List<int> inputs = new List<int>();
    int currentFloor = 1;
    int targetFloor = 1;
    bool IsGoingUp = true;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0,100);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start ();
    }

    private void buttonna4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        inputs.Add(4);
        // Recalculating target floor based on input
        RecalculateTargetFloor();
    }
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawAnimation(); // Draw small step of elevator to targetFloor
        if (currentFloor == targetFloor)
            RecalculateTargetFloor();
        //waiting for another tick of timer.
    }
```

Method `DrawAnimation ()` draws everything based on `currentFloor` and `targetFloor`. It also should recalculate target floor to handle when elevator reachs another target floor.

```
            private void RecalculateTargetFloor()
    {
        if (targetFloor > currentFloor)
        {
            //going up
            GetNextUpperFloor();
            return;
        }
        else if (targetFloor < currentFloor)
        {
            //going down
            GetNextLowerFloor();
            return;
        }

        // Elevator reached target              
        inputs.RemoveAll(x => x == targetFloor);

        if (IsGoingUp)
        {
            // if there is no any floors to go up - go down
            if (!inputs.Any(x => x > currentFloor))
            {
                IsGoingUp = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // or continue journey 
                GetNextUpperFloor();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!inputs.Any(x => x < currentFloor))
            {
                IsGoingUp = true;
            }
            else { GetNextLowerFloor(); }
        }
    }
```

And methods that calculate next station

```
    void GetNextUpperFloor()
    {
        var newTargetFloors = inputs.Where(x => x < targetFloor && x > currentFloor);
        if (newTargetFloors.Any())
        {
            targetFloor = newTargetFloors.Min();
        }
        else if (inputs.Any(x => x > currentFloor))
        {
            targetFloor = inputs.Where(x => x > currentFloor).Min();
        }
    }

    void GetNextLowerFloor()
    {
        var newTargetFloors = inputs.Where(x => x > targetFloor && x < currentFloor);
        if (newTargetFloors.Any())
        {
            targetFloor = newTargetFloors.Max();
        }
        else if (inputs.Any(x => x < currentFloor))
        {
            targetFloor = inputs.Where(x => x < currentFloor).Max();
        }
    }
```

You should be carreful with multitasking because you can break List, put some lockers if you have problems with deleting/inserting item from the list simultaneously.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. Your programming language is much more sophisticated than mine so I could use some more help. Are you sure that method which is Recalculating target floors is completed? I've created simple DrawAnimation() method which contains: if (targetFloor > currentFloor) elevator.margin.top -1          if (tagetFloor < currentFloor) elewator.margin.top +1 . But elevator doesn't move at all. From what I see even if I click on any buton elevator still thinks that targetfloor = currentfloor.

Comment: I've managed to make elevator move only by changing globally defined int currentfloor = 1; int targetfloor = 2;    So this makes me think that something is wrong with RecalculateTargetFloor() but unfortunately I can't figure out what :/

Comment: @Nollie You should change currentFloor variable when you change elevator position.

Comment: @Nollie variables should be defined in class, not in the method.

Comment: @Nollie Yes, I forgot to start timer! I updated the answer.

Comment: These variables are defined in class. But I can't change elevator position because even when I click button there is always currentfloor = targetfloor

Comment: Yeah, I noticed but I have started timer. Method DrawAnimation is executing but it always think that currentfloor=targetfloor

Comment: @Nollie I removed else statement in RecalculateTargetFloor, can you try it?

Comment: @Nollie I found mistake, on first tick of timer it's trying to get new floors to go up, but it can't find it, so it set isGoingUp to false and then constantly trying to get lower floors from input.

Comment: It's still not working, I've checked all if statments in RecalculateTargetFloor() with label.Content = "im here" but it never enter any of them.

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with inputs.RemoveAll(x => x == targetFloor); in RecalculateTargetFloor() but I'm not quite sure what is that for. For deleting floor that we've reached from target floor list?

Comment: @Nollie I've updated the answer, can you try it? Yes, RemoveAll(x => x == targetFloor removes current floor from target list when we reach that floor.

Comment: It's still not working. Maybe it would be easier for you if I would have send you my project with GUI so you could see it on your own with DrawAnimation() implemented?

Comment: Maybe you know which files exactly I have to send to make this work on your computer? Because I cant send whole folder ziped/rared because gmail blocks it.

Comment: @Nollie upload it somewhere and send a link

Comment: @Nollie I've updated the code. Also remove changing targetFloor variable in input handler.

Comment: Thank you once again. Now everything works as it should :)

Comment: Well this is strange. I was upvoting your answer all day long but I couldnt because I had not enough rep points, now I can haha :D